# How is praying different from begging?

Tags: prayer

Beggars always ask for something without giving any goods or services in return. Thats why they are often despised.

However, when we pray to God, we often make requests without giving anything in return. How is this different?

Comment: It depends how we pray. Do we pray with complete devotion and surrender?In its real process a devotee offers his devotion while praying , when he desperately in need of something on which his life depends.

Comment: The difference among the two is that in prayer, you are in awe of the entity you are praying to, while in begging, you do not care what sort of entity you are begging to is.

Comment: this is like asking *'how is requesting parents different from requesting strangers?'*

Comment: I think the answers to this will be primarily opinion based.

Comment: most of people who pray today are nothing much spiritual beggars. real prayer is not asking but thanking god for what you have... this is real prayer.